# "Switching" different cultures in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I am writing my own `TimeSpan` to ReadableString implementation. Now I need it to support different languages.

A functional class is implemented as a static class with two static public methods, both called Convert, but one receives just a TimeSpan value as a parameter, whereas the second one also allows to provide `CultureInfo` in order to specify, which is the desired readable string language.

My question is that my idea is to use basic switch(desiredCulture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName) and return different String.Format results.

Is a good approach, given a simple task I am trying to solve? Is using ThreeLetterISO anyhow more reliable and wide-spread then two letter codes for languages?

Comment: Why are you writing your own formatter? Aren't [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) `TimeSpan` format strings (available from .Net 4.0 up) enough for you?

Comment: @svick, not if you want to render the TimeSpan as "2 minutes and 30 seconds", or something like that...

Comment: @svick, thanks for a tip, but I am arriving at the same problem with the formater. For example ` output = "Time of Travel: " + duration.ToString("%d") + " days";` "days" is still in English, and I need to provide different "days" strings depending on a culture required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you don't actually want just to localize a `TimeSpan`, you want to localize your whole application. There are several ways how to do that (for example, there is a [weird, overcomplicated way specific to WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx)).

But my preferred way is to use resource files. You can have one culture-neutral resource file (e.g. `Text.resx`) and then one resource for each culture you want to support (e.g. `Text.de.resx` for German). If there is no resource for the currently set culture, the culture-neutral one is used.

Visual Studio has a editor for resource files, so making a translation is relatively simple.

Additionally, this might give you more details: [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx) (but resources are not specific to ASP.NET).

Comment: Assumption is not correct. The project is a dll that I am going to use in different solutions. A `TimeSpanToReadableString` is going to be a static class with hardcoded strings for different cultures. Localizing application is good when you are not planning to reuse code. Otherwise, for easily portable pure .dll assemblies, hard coding seems to be the only option.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, I don't think so. If you have the correct `CurrentUICulture` set, it affects code from libraries too. And the resources get compiled into the resulting assembly (.dll or .exe), so that should work for you too.